# How to pass in a String List to @Query in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I'm trying to pass in multiple words for a search algorithm to Neo4j's @Query annotation in Spring Boot. Here is what I'm trying:

```
@Query("WITH [{search}] AS sarray "
     + "MATCH (a:Node) "
     + "WHERE ALL(s IN sarray WHERE a.name=~('(?i).*'+s+'.*') " // <- This is known good regex
//The rest of the query which is known good
```

This query works perfectly in the Neo4j web interface like this:

```
WITH ["some","search","terms"] AS sarray
```

What I've tried:

- Passing in a single string with commas between the multiple words
- Passing into the {search} variable an ArrayList
- Passing into the {search} variable an array
- Removing the brackets in annotation
- Probable other things that didn't work either

The error that I get back says "Invalid Regex: Illegal repetition near index 5 (?i).*{search}.*^"

This regex does work before changing the query to include the multiple words.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
@Query("MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.id in $ids RETURN u.id as id")
List<String> findByIdIn(@Param("ids") List<String> ids);
```

Comment: This is something that I had already tried. The error mentioned above with 'Invalid Regex' is what I get. This tells me that the list gets passed in properly, but the WHERE ALL doesn't iterate through it.